# Efficiently UPDATE disk database from In-Memory

Tags: c++, sqlite, in-memory

I have an in-memory database which is replica of disk database. At some certain point, I want to UPDATE rows of disk database from in-memory database based on a WHERE clause.

Can someone suggest an efficient way to accomplish this functionality?

One less efficient possible solution is to first read all rows from in-memory database and then iterating the received rows  to UPDATE the disk database rows.

Just for understanding purpose, this is what I want to finally achieve:

```
UPDATE [disk db]Parameters SET [disk db]Value = [in-memory db]Value WHERE parametertype = 3
```

It should be possible by using [ATTACH](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html), if anyone can share some experience to use it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Use [ATTACH](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html).

Comment: right @CL.can you please provide some code snippet

Comment: What happened when you tried it?